# How can i use a seperate style / desing for the each first post of a collection of data?

Tags: php, css, laravel, eloquent

i have a collection of data with 7 single posts. After foreach that collection i want to use a separate design for only the first one but rest will be the same.

if i use two separate query, for the first one and the rest, it is possible but i want to do that only from one laravel eloquent query.(if possible)

[image]

can anyone please help me to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! You can use the $loop variable inside of blade loops!

Ex:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)

  <div class="post {{ $loop->first ? 'featured-post' : '' }}">
    {{-- Post content here --}}
  </div>

@endforeach
```

Using a ternary operator the class 'featured-post' will be added only on the first iteration. Then you can write special CSS rules for it.

More here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable

Comment: awesome with reference of laravel documentation